# Is there an earth bridge missing in my PV installation?

Tags: grounding, photovoltaic

In the DC installation depicted in the following image, is there a bridge missing in the earth distribution in the center? The top right earth wire is coming from the potential distribution rail visible in the bottom right of the picture.

[image]